# mySQL count occurances of a string

Tags: mysql

I have this query...

```
SELECT SUM(brownlow_votes) AS votes, 
player_id, 
player_name, 
player_team, 
COUNT(*) AS vote_count 
FROM afl_brownlow_phantom, afl_playerstats 
WHERE player_id=brownlow_player 
AND brownlow_match=player_match 
GROUP BY player_id 
ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT 50
```

So "votes" becomes the number of votes a player has, "vote_count" becomes the number of times (matches in which) a player has been voted for. This works fine.

However, I have another column called "brownlow_lock" which is either blank, or 'Y'. How do I get the number of occurances of 'Y'? I know I could solve this changing it to 0 or 1 and just doing a SUM() but I don't want to have to go and edit the tons of pages that are inserting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you just need to add

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN brownlow_lock='Y' THEN 1 END) AS Cnt
```

to your query

Comment: Thanks Martin, that only counts if there is a 'Y' for that player though? Sometimes they have more than 1...

Comment: Actually, I might be wrong here, I think I have a mistake in my query, it's not actually counting all the votes. I'll come back to this!

Comment: @Mark - If there is more than one `Y` within a group they will be counted. Is that the desired result?

Comment: The "1" in there is for counting, not the result. It will give you what you are after

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [IF control flow function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

> SELECT SUM(IF(brownlow_lock='Y',1,0)) lock_count ...

Comment: Hi Fredrik, I tried that but it didnt work right. The answer above works well though. Thanks anyway :)